# unknown field "resources" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

_helper.tpl

```
{{- define "fluentd-config" -}}
image: {{ .Values.fluentd.kinesis_image }}
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 200Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 200Mi
{{- end -}}
```

deployment.yaml

```
- name: log-agent
  {{ include "fluentd-configuration" . | indent 2 }}
```

But I encountered, following error message

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "resources" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec
```

Please let me know why I got that one. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the values for all the fields? And the indentation of content from `include` and 'value` in helper.tpl?

Comment: @Bimal yap, we have value.

Comment: @PPShein Can you add the result of `$ helm template <name>  <chart> ` command?

Comment: @KamolHasan it's indenting issue that I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'd expect to see a YAML syntax error from what you've shown, but not that validation error.  (You have two spaces before the `{{`, and then `indent` indents every line including the first one two spaces more; so you have the first line, then a line with four spaces, then a line with two spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Deployment file should look something like below:

deployment.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-name
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      apps: my-demo-app # <-- here
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        apps: my-demo-app # <-- make sure it match the `matchLabels`
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: log-agent
{{include "fluentd-config" .| indent 8}} # (8 spaces added)
```

Comment: so sweet. the last line saved my time, appreciate it.